# qcut to return bin numbers inversely

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a column to return bin values (quintiles) but I want it to return the numbers in a descending format (i.e. 5,4,3,2,1)

The current formula I have is:

```
df['test'] = pd.qcut(df['ColumnA'], q=5, labels= False) + 1
```

I tried to order my data in DESC and ASC but the result is still the same.

```
ColumnA test
2   1
2   1
3   2
3   2
4   3
4   3
5   4
5   4
6   5
6   5
```

I want the test to return the bin numbers in a descending format.

The expected output should like :

```
ColumnA test        
2   5
2   5
3   4
3   4
4   3
4   3
5   3
5   3
6   1
6   1
```

Comment: So for ColumnA = 2 you want 5?

Comment: Instead of adding 1, subtract it from 5 (number of bins)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on @ayhan comment, do:

```
df['test'] = 5 - pd.qcut(df['ColumnA'], q=5, labels= False)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   ColumnA  test
0        2     5
1        2     5
2        3     4
3        3     4
4        4     3
5        4     3
6        5     2
7        5     2
8        6     1
9        6     1
```